# CSound for Android, will not find wav files

Tags: csound

I'm trying to figure out how to get wav  recognized. A tutorial that uses a wav, which was included, won't find it. It is in the same folder as the .csd file. I have tried copying it to the Root folder, no luck. I have tried modifying the csd to included the full path to the wav, no luck. I have tried modifying the Settings "Sample folder" option. Still no luck.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: By req, the code that was giving me problems: 
Sound = “input.wav”
   
aSound = diskin:a(Sound,iSpeed,iStart,1)
aOut = linen:a(aSound,p3/2,p3,p3/2)
  
Solved. I found 3 solutions:
 
1. modify the .csd file ex:
 
Sound = "/storage/emulated/0/folder/input.wav"
 
2. add "/storage/emulated/0/folder/" to Settings - Sample dir.
 
3. add the line "/storage/emulated/0/folder/" to Settings - Include dir
 
Latter 2 options b best no need to modify every .csd that you intend to load a sample into, just place input samples in designated directories.

Comment: I apologize but formatting in this forum is problematic. It will not allow added comments to use proper spaces and paragraph separation. Comments written do not appear on page as typed.